# Server Always Needing Apache Restart Why?

Tags: wordpress, whm

Sir, My sites are not able to access from web browser till they have apache restart.!

My sites opening in web browser only when I restart my apache then afater few minutes it again goes to offline !

Why It happening with my server ?

Please Help Me..!

Answer (score 0):

check for any issues in the 'ErrorLog'. The location of the error log can be obtained from your apache config file which is located in

```
/etc/apache2/http.conf
```

Edit:

look for

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Sorry for the typo

Comment: root@server [~]# /etc/apache2/http.conf
-bash: /etc/apache2/http.conf: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your wamp/Xamp Server , Run as Administrator.